# Publishing failed

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.  Some of the pages/components are getting failed while publishing with below mentioned error.

```
Phase: Deployer Prepare Phase failed, Unable to unzip,
D:\Inetpub\TridionPublisherFS4SP\incoming\tcm_0-286137-66560.Content.zip (The process 
cannot access the file because it is being used by another process), 
D:\Inetpub\TridionPublisherFS4SP\incoming\tcm_0-286137-66560.Content.zip (The process 
cannot access the file because it is being used by another process), Unable to unzip, 
D:\Inetpub\TridionPublisherFS4SP\incoming\tcm_0-286137-66560.Content.zip (The process 
cannot access the file because it is being used by another process), 
D:\Inetpub\TridionPublisherFS4SP\incoming\tcm_0-286137-66560.Content.zip (The process 
cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

Components/Pages are failing under stage `Preparing Deployment`, how should we fix it?

Comment: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" -- Antivirus?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have multiple Deployers using the same incoming location?

It looks like you’re running the Deployer as a WebApp – is the Deployer service also running on the system?

If you search for all files named “cd_deployer_conf.xml”, do they have the same incoming folder (D:\Inetpub\TridionPublisherFS4SP\incoming) defined?

Otherwise, you might use [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch the folder and see what else is accessing the file.

Comment: We have only one deployer, yes the folder path "(D:\Inetpub\TridionPublisherFS4SP\incoming)" is correctly configured in “cd_deployer_conf.xml

Comment: What specific version are you using - This appears to be resolved by Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

Comment: Yes we are using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this issue, you may try 
1. deleting all files under incoming, 
2. making sure there is no encryption enabled for the incoming folder (Some companies apply encrypt script immediately to the files that are added to the drive) or 
3. making sure your antivirus is not screening that folder (As Nuno mentioned).

Do a restart of the deployer app and verify in the logs?